# Subsetting within a range in R

Tags: r

So I'd like to subset my dataset based on two dates. 
I have a variable that is indicative of chemo start date and a second data for lab visit.

I'd like to subset my dataset so that only those lab records that were taken a year before or a year after chemo start data remain.

I am currently using the following code:

```
df$lower <- df$ChemoDate - 365 #1 year earlier chemo start date
df$upper <- df$ChemoDate + 365 #1 year after chemo start date 
df <- subset(df, LabDate == (ChemoDate > lower & ChemoDate < upper)) 
#only keep records that have a lab date within a year before or after chemo date
```

Once I run this code, I end up with 0 observations. Can anyone please help? Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the type of "LabDate"? In your subset function, the right hand side of the == evaluates to a logical (TRUE/FALSE). You would only get an observation if LabDate is logical and matches whatever (ChemoDate < lower...) results to. I think you want to use %in%

Comment: Your subset is currently based on LabDate being equal to a True/ False. since you've already taken and added the year, would it look right to use subset(df, Labdate > lower & labDate < upper). difficult to fully verify without data, but this seems most likely the issue

Comment: the %in% command worked, thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Chris Littler's solution also works. I am more used to the tidyverse than base R functions, so here is the tidyverse equivalent:

```
library(tidyverse)

new_df <- filter(df, LabDate > lower & LabDate < upper)
```

With fake data to confirm that it does what you hoped:

```
library(tidyverse)

## make fake data

df <- tibble(
  a = letters[1:10],
  LabDate = sample(500:1500, 10),
  ChemoDate = sample(700:800, 10)
)

df
#> # A tibble: 10 x 3
#>    a     LabDate ChemoDate
#>    <chr>   <int>     <int>
#>  1 a        1419       749
#>  2 b         945       738
#>  3 c         935       735
#>  4 d         956       777
#>  5 e        1299       763
#>  6 f         759       792
#>  7 g        1439       782
#>  8 h         964       779
#>  9 i        1091       785
#> 10 j        1491       736

## apply your code

df$lower <- df$ChemoDate - 365
df$upper <- df$ChemoDate + 365

## suggested solution

new_df <- filter(df, LabDate > lower & LabDate < upper)

new_df
#> # A tibble: 6 x 5
#>   a     LabDate ChemoDate lower upper
#>   <chr>   <int>     <int> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 b         945       738   373  1103
#> 2 c         935       735   370  1100
#> 3 d         956       777   412  1142
#> 4 f         759       792   427  1157
#> 5 h         964       779   414  1144
#> 6 i        1091       785   420  1150
```